# file_get_contents(/target/file/here/file.json): Failed to open stream: Permission denied in homepage.php

Tags: php, apache, redhat, selinux

I'm trying to read a json file from my php code by using file_get_contents but I get "Failed to open stream: Permission denied", but it worked when I tried to make selinux in Permissive mode.
My is how I can allow file_get_contents to read files without turning on selinux in Permessive mode ?

Note : I'm using httpd server in redhat 7

Trying :

```
           $json = file_get_contents('/target/file/here/file.json');
           //modify json file
           file_put_contents('new_file.json', $Json_to_put);
```

Expecting :

1- file_get_content read my file.json
2- file_put_contents create my new_file.json

Comment: What are permissions for file/folder and which user is apache running as?

Comment: You'll need RW- permissions inside of that directory for that specified user. You can achieve that easily by setting the owner to `www-data` (assuming httpd uses that user) with `chown`. Something like: `chown -R www-data:www-data /target`. You could then `chmod` if you need read access to other users (4).

Comment: Tnx for your answer, I steel have the same problem after applying this changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

1. Change the owner of the webroot

   chown -R apache:apache /target/file/here
2. Change the basic permissions

   chmod -R g+w /target/file/here

   chmod g+s /target/file/here

Answer (score 0):

1. Permissions would need to be accessable

```
//Partial Headers from a 3rd party JSON based API I have access too
"headers":
  {"Access-Control-Allow-Headers":"Content-Type,
   Access-Control-Allow-Headers, 
   Access-Control-Allow-Origin, 
   Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
   "Access-Control-Allow-Origin":"*",
   "Access-Control-Allow-Methods":"GET",
   "Content-Type":"application/json"}
```

You can see the access allows origin of "*", control-method of "GET"

Also - you may want to decode the json..

```
$json = json_decode(file_get_content($url), false);
// False returns an Object and True returns an Array.
```

> You're doing this from a file on the server, so this likely won't apply, but just for future reference - I've also run into problems when a 3rd party API (in JSON) is encoded, so watch for [GZ Encoding](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gzread.php), or other types of Encoding. The link I used to grab the above info is GZ encoded.

You should then be able to edit the data and `file_put_content` the data back to the file.

When you create the file, be sure to add the proper permissions. [PHP File Create/Write](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_create.asp)